# jQuery Mobile & PhoneGap deviceReady() not fired

Tags: jquery, android, eclipse, mobile, cordova

i am trying to create a new Android project with PhoneGap 1.3.0. and JqueryMobile. But te problem is, if i use Only Phone Gap test code Phone Gap works! DeviceReady function is fired.  Please look the examles

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Test Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="docs/assets/css/jqm-docs.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="docsdemos-style-override.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


    var onDeviceReady = function() {
        document.getElementById("devready").innerHTML = "OnDeviceReady fired.";
    };

    function init() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
    }   
</script>  
</head> 
<body > 

<div data-role="page" id="konum" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Position</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content"> 
<p>APP will go here.</p>
<p>
<span id="devready">DeviceReady() Not Fired.</span>
</p>
</div>
```

But i want to use jQuery paging functionality. And the result:  Deviceready not fired. What is the problem. How it is possible to use both PhoneGap javascript codes and jQuery library.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test Page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="docs/assets/css/jqm-docs.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="docsdemos-style-override.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


        var onDeviceReady = function() {
            document.getElementById("devready").innerHTML = "OnDeviceReady fired.";
        };

        function init() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
        }   
    </script>  
    </head> 
    <body > 
    <div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="a">

    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content"> 
    <div data-role="content" id="twitList" >
    something will go here
    </div>   
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home" id="home" data-icon="custom">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about" id="about" data-icon="custom">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#konum" id="konum" data-icon="custom">Position</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" id="contact" data-icon="custom">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </div>

    <!------page seperator --------> 

    <div data-role="page" id="about" data-theme="a">

    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>About</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content"> 
    <p>Hoopp! <a href="#home">Back</a></p>    
    </div>
   <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home" id="home" data-icon="custom">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about" id="about" data-icon="custom">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#konum" id="konum" data-icon="custom">Position</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" id="contact" data-icon="custom">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </div>
    <!------page seperator --------> 


    <div data-role="page" id="konum" data-theme="a">

    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Position</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content"> 


    <p>APP will go here.</p>
    <p>
    <span id="devready">DeviceReady() Not Fired.</span>
    </p>

    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home" id="home" data-icon="custom">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about" id="about" data-icon="custom">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#konum" id="konum" data-icon="custom">Position</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" id="contact" data-icon="custom">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </div>

    </body>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You placed `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);` inside `init` but never actually call it to make initialization. So the listener for `deviceready` is not attached. Try changing to:

```
$(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
});
```

Comment: or change the body tag to <body onload="init();">

Comment: Thank you man. It works i am working on this issue for 2-3 days :)

Answer (score 6):

This is the equivalent;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
});
```

Comment: Equivalent of/for what?

Answer (score 0):

When I converted my project to include iPhone I had to change to `document.addEventListener`.